# Binary search for samller elements

Tags: java, algorithm

i wanted my program to return the
number of elements that are smaller than the key and a also it's similar
and count how many duplicated element we have

Notice everything in the comments my first attempt i tried to approach (remove linked list and swap it with int )

Second one it worked fine but no one likes spaghetti code and it also made confusion with my second attempt!

help :library approach or algorithmic approach(preferable)

PS:my English is terrific :p

First Attempt:

Input:1 4 6 7 8 8 8 11 30

output:[7, 6, 4, 1]

what i want
output:[8,8,8,7, 6, 4, 1]

2 //count of how many duplicate we have

```
public static   LinkedList<Integer> BinarySearch(int []arr ,int key) {

    LinkedList<Integer> ll=new LinkedList<>();

    int start=0;
    int end=arr.length-1;

    while(start<=end) {
        int mid=start+((end-start)/2);

        if (arr[mid]>key)end=mid-1;
        if (arr[mid]<key)start=mid+1;
        else {

            int key2=arr[mid];
            while(--mid>=0 && key2==key) {
                ll.add(arr[mid]); //return mid+1
            }
            return ll;
        }
    }
    return null;//return 0
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: also print duplicated values

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have a nasty bug in your condition check:

```
if (arr[mid]>key)end=mid-1;
if (arr[mid]<key)start=mid+1;
else {
```

The three conditions should be mutually exclusive. In your version they aren't. It should be:

```
if (arr[mid]>key)end=mid-1;
else if (arr[mid]<key)start=mid+1;
else {
```

As for returning and counting duplicates keys, when there are duplicate values in your array there are no guarantees that your binary search will hit the rightmost instance. When you match the key you therefore have to first move right in the array until you longer have a match, then move left to the start of the array, adding elements and counting key matches.

```
if (arr[mid]>key) end=mid-1;
else if (arr[mid]<key) start=mid+1;
else {
    int right = mid+1;
    while(right < arr.length && arr[right] == key) 
        right++;

    int keyCount = 0;
    for(int i=right-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(arr[i] == key) keyCount++;
        ll.add(arr[i]); 
    }
    System.out.format("Duplicates: %d%n", keyCount-1);
    return ll;
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(BinarySearch(new int[] {1,4,6,7,8,8,8,11,30}, 8));
```

Output:

```
Duplicates: 2
[8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1]
```